# Least squares solution to overdetermined $AX=B$ where each matrix is a rotation

Tags: matrices, optimization, least-squares

I can't seem to find anything that would help me with this particular problem. I have a bunch of measurements of a matrix $A$ and corresponding matrix $B$, which I know are related by a third rotation $X$ ($3\times 3$ matrices). How do I arrive at a least squares solution to $X$ where $X$ is constrained to be a rotation?

I thought maybe SVD could be employed somehow, but the approach is not obvious to me.

Comment: When you say in your title that each matrix is a rotation, is that just a typo, or do you mean that, say, $A$ and $B$ are semi-orthogonal with $X$ a proper rotation matrix?

Comment: If they are all measurements of the *same* matrices $A$ and $B$, why wouldn't you compute the means $\bar A$ and $\bar B$ and then solve $X = \bar A^{-1}\bar B$? If you have measurements of *different* matrices $A_1X\approx B_1,A_2X\approx B_2,\dots$, see [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem). In particular, you want to minimize $\|X^T [A_1^T, A_2^T, \dots] - [B_1^T, B_2^T, \dots]\|_F$.

Comment: To some extent this is the same as [Wahba's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem), though the fact that $A,B\in SO(3)$ might possibly change things a bit.